# Express routing - Redirect based on locale

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, localization

I am trying to set up routing for my multilingual website. My goal is to redirect the user based on his language (which is already detected).

This is my current unfinished code:

```
app.get('/(:lang)?', (req, res, next) => {
    const urlLang = req.params.lang || 'en'; // English is default
    const userLang = 'nl'; // Will be detected

    if (urlLang !== userLang) {
        // Wrong URL
        res.redirect(userLang + req.url);
    } else next();
});
```

In this example I try to subtract the requested language from the url (`urlLang`). If that language does not match the users language, then it should redirect to the proper URL.

A few examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

- User with language `en` requests `/`: No redirect
- User with language `nl` requests `/`: Redirect to `/nl`
- User with language `en` requests `/foo/bar`: No redirect
- User with language `nl` requests `/foo/bar`: Redirect to `/nl/foo/bar`

My current code only works if the requested path is `/` or `/:lang`, but not for routes like `/home` or `/nl/home`. I don't see how this can be achieved with express. Any help will be much appreciated!

---

*Please note I have already set up everything else, like language detection, translation logic, views, etc. I am only asking about the routing.*

Answer (score 1):

If you know all language identifiers that need to be supported in advance then this should work:

```
api.get('/(:lang(en|nl)/)?*', ( req, res, next ) => {
```